# How to create a report navigation in Power BI

Tags: navigation, click, powerbi, ctrl

I have created a home page with button and I want to navigate on next tab when click on button.

I am able to do it using Bookmarks the pages and Add Bookmarks in action of respective button.

For this, I need to press `ctrl + click` to navigate next tab. My requirement is it should navigate to next page without using `ctrl` only click on button.

Comment: ctrl is required only in Power BI Desktop, but when it is getting published into Power BI service account then you may not need to do that. By simple mouse click, it will do magic for navigating into the corresponding screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctrl` is required only in ***Power BI Desktop*** since you are editing desktop file, but when it is getting published into ***Power BI service*** account then you may not need that. By clicking a simple mouse click on all bookmarks/buttons, it will do magic for navigating into the corresponding screen.

Hope this answers your query.!